# Resize image for download client side

Tags: javascript, html, air

Is there any way through any type of client side script to get an external image (ex: http://www.google.com/image.jpg) and resize it when the user copies the image so that the pasted image will be resized? And I can't get HTML5 canvas to work.

I'm working out of Dreamweaver CS5.5 and creating an Air App. The code works in live view but not when I preview the Air App. Here is the code that is not working:

```
function test(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
};


img.src="image.jpg";

 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't there is a way to do it client-side without canvas, simply because there's no other way to access the raw image data to perform any operations on it (such as resizing the image). I guess you could write a third-party browser plugin....

Comment: If I put the script in the body, below the canvas tag, it will work onLoad. But it will not work triggered as a function.

Comment: Well how are you triggering the function? If the JS is before the canvas tag, then the element won't be available unless you're executing on DOMReady or on page load.

Comment: I think that is my issue. I have the function after the canvas tag but it's still not working.

Comment: Try adding "window.onload = test;" after the function definition.

Comment: That works but the image changes so I need to load dynamic images. That is not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9880/discussion-between-user899641-and-jeff)

Answer (score 0):

You can try drawing the image then doing `img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` prior to the user dragging. This will cause the canvas to output its data to the image tag. The canvas should be invisible, while the image is the visible element the user should drag.

To resize the image, specify the width and height in the [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Scaling).

Comment: Back to the same issue. I need to get the canvas to work in Air first. If I can get that to load then I can get the resize and toDataURL to work.

Comment: The code works in a browser but will not work when I create the Air App through Dreamweaver.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with AIR or Dreamweaver-specific stuff :(